# How do you iterate through a data frame based on the value in a row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which I am trying to iterate through, however not based on time, but on an increase of 10 for example

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 12:05 | 1 |
| 13:05 | 6 |
| 14:05 | 11 |
| 15:05 | 16 |

so in this case it would return a new data frame with the rows with 1 and 11. How am I able to do this? The different methods that I have tried such as asfreq resample etc. don't seem to work. They say invalid frequency. The reason I think about this is that it is not time based. What is the function that allows me to do this that isn't time based but based on a numerical value such as 10 or 7. I don't want the every nth number, but every time the column value changes by 10 from the last selected value. ex 1 to 11 then if the next values were 12 15 17 21, it would be 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# do a remainder division, and choose rows where remainder is zero
# offset by the first value, to make calculation simpler

first_val = df.loc[0]['Column B']
df.loc[((df['Column B'] - first_val) % 10).eq(0)]
```

```
Column A    Column B
0   12:05   1
2   14:05   11
```